# VSTS git with Visual Studio 2017 - Glitch with Files

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

We are using VSTS git repository and at times, changes already committed by one developer (say David) appears in the changes list in Visual Studio for another dev (say Mark) as if the changes are made by Mark?

These changes shouldn't appear in the changes for Mark as these are by David and Mark should only see changes he has made.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For clarification - one developer do a commit and another developer see the changes?

Comment: What does the output of `git config --get user.name` and `git config --get user.email` look like for these two people?

Comment: How did Mark make these changes? Did he pull changes (including changes made by David) remote repo and there has merge conflicts? So please provider more details and related screen shots?